# $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} \frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}$ doesn't exist (?)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Is what I did correct?

We have: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} \frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}$

We know that as $x\rightarrow 0$ $\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3}=1$ , can be proven using taylor series..

So we have: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3} \frac{x^4}{yx^2+y^3}$

Pose $y=Cx^2$ we get: $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3} \frac{x^4}{Cx^4+C^3x^6}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3} \frac{x^4}{x^4(C+C^3x^2)}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3} \frac{1}{(C+C^3x^2)}=\frac{1}{(C+C^3x^2)}$$

Which is dependent on the constant $C$, Hence the limit doesn't exist.

What i'm doubtful about is the usage of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3}=1$ in double variable limits, What i thought was since $x$ is still tending towards zero, and these terms are independent of y I can use it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you derivation is correct, indeed since $x\to 0$

$$\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x^3}\to1$$

it is true and we can conclude that for the trajectories $y=Cx^2\to 0$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow0} \frac{x\ln(1+x^3)}{y(x^2+y^2)}=\frac1C$$

then the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: But both are tending towards $0$ which means it's $0/0$

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Yes but you are allowed to chose a trajectory with $x=0$.

Comment: But that's just one trajectory that tends to $0$, i'd need another trajectory that tends to another limit i guess?

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Yes exactly, the second trajectory you choose indeed leads to $1/C$.

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Yes sorry I don't know why but I read badly and I thought you had also a doubt for the case x=0. Do not consider that. Your derivation for the trajectories $ y=Cx^2$ of course suffices to show that the limit doesn't exist,

Comment: Guys, I don't have any confusion about the trajectory, All i'm asking is whether what i did is not wrong, finding the result $1/C$ is already enough to conclude it's not existent, I want to know whether what i did is actually correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Have a nice day

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Yes now it is clear, sorry for the confusion! Very nice job! ;)